# Problem reading ANSII Encoded CSV file with CSVHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the CSVHelper to read a CSV file which contains some characters such as the GBP character (eg £2000)

However when processing the file, the pound symbol is lost and instead a diamond with a question mark appears.

My code is as follows:

```
        var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
        {
            ShouldSkipRecord = (row) =>
            {
                if (row.Row.Parser.Row <= 4)
                {
                    return true;
                } else
                {
                    return false;
                }                    
            }
        };

        using var streamReader = File.OpenText(_fileName);
        using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfig);
        
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<WebApi.Entities.Csv.Transaction();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(record.PaidIn);
        }
```

The above code outputs the field containing the pound symbol with a diamond question mark instead .. eg : ?2000

I cannot convert the source file to UTF-8 before processing it.  However I have tried converting it to UTF-8 in the function above and that did not work.

I'm at a lost and need some guidance.

---- UPDATE ----------------------------------

After reading the comments I have proceeded as suggested by detecting the encoding of the file and then passing to a StreamReader:

```
    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
    {
        ShouldSkipRecord = (row) =>
        {
            if (row.Row.Parser.Row <= 4)
            {
                return true;
            } else
            {
                return false;
            }                    
        }
    };

    //get current encoding of source csv file
    var reader = new StreamReader(_fileName, Encoding.Default, true);
    if (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        reader.Read();
    Encoding encoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;

    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(_fileName, reader.CurrentEncoding);
    using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfig);
    
    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<WebApi.Entities.Csv.Transaction>();

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(record.PaidIn);
    }
```

But all is in vein, this still does not resolve the original problem.

Comment: First, you need to determine which text encoding (i.e., code page) the text file is using (written with). Then, instead of using File.OpenText, use the StreamReader constructor that allows you to pass the text encoding you have figured out...

Comment: Would you show me how to get the encoding of the file?

Comment: £ is not part of the standard ASCII 7-bit character set.  If your file really is an 8-bit (not UTF8) encoding, then you need to work out which 'code-page', so that it can be decoded into .NET strings (which are actually Unicode under the hood).  What program created the text file?  Is that under your control?  Can you tell what encoding is used?

Comment: According to notepad++ the file is ANSII Encoded.  Any code samples to get it either read correctly or converted to UTF-8?

Comment: It could be code-page 850, as according to this page https://www.aivosto.com/articles/charsets-codepages-dos.html#codepage850 that has a £ symbol and is for Western European cultures.

Comment: ANSI is not an encoding (technically, there was a draft for an "ANSI" encoding in ancient past). "ANSI" is these days commonly used as a catch-all phrase for many encodings/code pages that encode western characters in a single byte. Therefore, Notepad++ showing ANSI is not really that helpful with regard to your problem.

Comment: After reading the comments, i'm realising I need help getting the current encoding / codepage and using the streamreader to read the file using that encoding when passing it to the CSV Helper.  I'm trying some code samples but they have been fruitless so far.  Any code samples would be higely appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding. In .Net Core and 5+ only the west european ansi code page is avaiable. Others must be installed.

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code - the question currently completely missing data that you trying to read and instead has unconventional description of what data is. You need to [edit] the question to include smallest possible (probably one line long) example of data as HEX-encoded sequence of bytes, while editing make sure to remove all code not directly related to the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to read this row and write it to another file? Is there `?` sign or `£` sign after saving? Do you observe the same behavior If you set a breakpoint there and hover over the field?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, attempting to detect the encoding of the current file resulted in ain correct encoding being returned by .NET, I therefore specified the encoding manually:

```
using var streamReader = new StreamReader(_fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

The above solved my issue.